# CSS Remove Last Overflow Line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

im already try ellipsis, but it doesnt work

```
.collection-item-text {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;   
    color: #404d57;
}
```

http://codepen.io/putrafajar/pen/XKMxEq

[image]

Comment: Check this link [Multi line ellipsis](https://jsfiddle.net/m8xdws6L/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text-overflow: ellipsis` work only on one line text.

For multiline text, as you need, you can use the approach suggested [here](https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/)

Here a possible usage:

```
.collection-item-text {
  max-height: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
  width: 250px
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;   
    color: #404d57;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 6;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

Hope it helps.
Simone

Comment: this work cross major browser? like opera, safari, chrome, firefox, android browser, UC Browser?

Comment: I'm afraid not. You can check here --> http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-line-clamp

You can use another approach. Here an example:


`.line-clamp:after {
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #FFFFFF 50%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
bottom: 0;
content: "...";
font-weight: bold;
padding: 0 20px 1px 45px;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
}`


[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/DpQ7e/30/) an example of the result